# C++ Return the reference of an array

Tags: c++

The original question is exercise 6.36 in *C++ Primer 5th*.

It wants a declaration which returns the reference of an array including 10 strings.

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/Mooophy/Cpp-Primer/blob/master/ch06/README.md).

But when I test it, gdb tells me it returns a `int *` variable.

Here is how my test goes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int array[10] = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
};

int (&func())[10]{
    int (&a)[10] = array;
    return a;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto t = func();             // line 18
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute `print t` in the line 18, gdb tells me:

```
(gdb) print t
$1 = (int *) 0x555555558020 <array>
```

My question: Is this answer correct? If it is, then what leads to this test result?

Comment: Please don't upload pictures of your code, provide the code as text in your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: oh, sorry for that

Comment: `auto& t = func()`, to avoid decay to pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this answer correct?

It is a declaration of a function that returns reference to an array of 10 int.

> gdb tells me it returns a int * variable.

No it doesn't. It tells you that the variable `t` that you created is an `int *` variable.